# DBCC CLONEDATABASE exception 12605 : Failed to create snapshot database

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

I'm executing the following instruction :

```
DBCC CLONEDATABASE(mydb_prod, mydb_clone)
```

And here is the exception I get :

> Database cloning for 'mydb_prod' has started with target as
> 'mydb_clone'. Msg 12605, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Failed to create
> snapshot database.

I looked into SQL Server logs, and only get :

> Database cloning for 'sqllog_ivalua_prod' has started with target as
> 'sqllog_ivalua_clone'.

I've searched the Internet, with no answer.
There is plenty of free disk space on the target volume.
No user object is in the model database.

I looked into Extended Events to find out whether there are events related to cloning a database, or any DBCC command, but none related to cloning.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: A couple of suggestions: 1) consider truncating your log, and try the clone again. 
 2) See if "dbcc checkdb" (or equivalent) also causes the same problem.  3) See https://www.sqlshack.com/meaning-of-5127-database-snapshot-error-code/ or https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/database-snapshots-when-things-go-wrong/.  ALSO:  Consider posting on serverfault.com (vs. SO).  'Hope that helps!

Comment: Did you look in Windows Event Viewer? What is the status of the drive where the source database lives? Empty? Full? Working correctly? Are you sure you are looking at the right disk target? Permissions changed?